# Email Notification not delivered to customers in Magento

Tags: magento, email, notifications, e-commerce, admin

I am new to Magento. As an admin i am getting email notifications on orders. But customer doesn't get any email notification on orders, password reset, etc. Is there any settings to be enabled it for customers?

Answer (score 1):

First, in your admin panel under "System->Configuration" menu :

1. "General->Store Email Addresses" : you can set sender email here
2. Advanced->System" : in "mail sending settings" section, be sure to configure :

   Disable Email Communications => No

Next, you have ton configure SMTP setting to prevent your mails from being recognized as spam.
Install and configure [SMTP Pro Extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html) and you're done.

Comment: Spent days, till late at night trying to fix this. I had installed the plugin and it would NOT work...(stupid gmail lol) and it never occurred to me to use the email from the cpanel. If someone else reads this, setup an email in cpanel and configure this to use that. Works perfectly, emails sending for order confirmations in 10 seconds! (Also AOE Scheduler for cron job automation if you want)